# Библиотека для удаление из слова приставки, суффикса и окончания (выделение корня) Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, морфология

В своей курсовой, решил использовать неточный поиск, поэтому для увеличения шансов найти правильный ответ необходима библиотека, которая из слова вычленяет корень.
Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то скинет ссылку.

Comment: лучше спрашивать "как сделать X" (ответ пример кода) вместо "дайте ссылку на библиотеку по теме X" (ответ набор ссылок). Второй тип вопроса более уместен для гугла, а не Stack Overflow (не случайно, что на английском SO это вообще offtopic).

Answer (score 7):

С [лемматизацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) русских слов дела, насколько я знаю, обстоят не самым лучшим образом.

Есть "альфа" версия библиотеки [pymystem3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymystem3/0.1.0):

```
>>> from pymystem3 import Mystem
>>> text = "Красивая мама красиво мыла раму"
>>> m = Mystem()
>>> lemmas = m.lemmatize(text)
>>> print(''.join(lemmas))
красивый мама красиво мыть рама
```

до нахождения корней этой библиотеке еще далеко:

```
In [104]: ' '.join(m.lemmatize('ко мне вчера приехали родственники двоюродной сестры моей жены'))
Out[104]: 'ко   я   вчера   приезжать   родственник   двоюродный   сестра   мой   жена \n'
```

практически такой же результат дает [модуль pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
In [113]: text = "ко мне вчера приехали родственники двоюродной сестры моей жены"

In [114]: import pymorphy2

In [115]: morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

In [116]: ' '.join([morph.normal_forms(w)[0] for w in text.split()])
Out[116]: 'к я вчера приехать родственник двоюродный сестра мой жена'
```

Answer (score 3):

1. В [NLTK](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk) есть `nltk.stem.snowball.RussianStemmer`;
2. Есть [PyStemmer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyStemmer/1.3.0);
3. Вот [ещё один результат](https://gist.github.com/Kein1945/9111512) с первой страницы поиска в Google.